# How to add a random value every time when user logs in in python using sql and update it every time

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to implement a method (log_in())that will allow me to add a random number to a column called "money" every time a user logs in to the system. For example, when we execute log_in() method and user successfully logs in, a number lets say from 1-10 should be added to a column money. In more details let's say user 1 logs in on Monday and the code automatically adds a number from 1-10 and saves it. on Tuesday user logs back in and the system adds another random number from 1-10 to that existing number. I hope that makes sense. Thank you

```
class Database(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.login_code = ""

def clear_console(self):
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    return self

def txt_menu(self):
    self.clear_console()
    terms_conditions()
    checking = input("> Proceed? ")
    if checking == "a":
        self.clear_console()
        self.user_menu()
    else:
        self.txt_menu()

def loading_bar(self):
    for _ in tqdm(range(101), "> Loading. . .", ncols=75):
        time.sleep(0.01)
    print("> Complete. . .")
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    return self

def user_menu(self):
    print("")
    process = input("> Are you registered y/n? Or forgot details 'f': ")
    if process == "y":
        self.log_in()
    elif process == "n":
        self.user_registration()
    elif process == "f":
        self.forgot_details()
    else:
        print("Try again! ")
        self.user_menu()

def user_registration(self):
    global registration_code
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    print("> To register enter the details below: \n")
    registration_username = input("> Username: ")
    registration_email = input("> Email: ")
    registration_password = input("> Password: ")

    for pwd in range(1):
        registration_code = ""
    for c in range(5):
        registration_code += random.choice(chars)

    blank = ""

    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO upgr (username, email, password, code, money) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                   registration_username, registration_email, registration_password, registration_code, blank)
    print("> Your code is: ", registration_code)
    print("> Successful registration")
    print("")
    print("> Welcome", registration_username)
    conn.commit()
    print("> To continue, please enter your code")
    self.log_in()
    return self

def log_in(self):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    self.login_code = input("Enter the code: ")
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM upgr WHERE code = ?", self.login_code)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    if not data:
        print('> Not found')
        self.log_in()
    else:
        cursor.execute("SELECT username FROM upgr WHERE code = ?", self.login_code)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        reducing_string = str(data)[1:-1]
        last_cut = str(reducing_string)[1:-1]

        #  WORKING ON RANDOM

        print("")
        self.clear_console()
        print("> Welcome", last_cut)
        self.who()
        return self.login_code

def forgot_details(self):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    login_username = input("> Username: ")
    login_password = input("> Password: ")
    cursor.execute("SELECT code FROM upgr WHERE username = ? AND password = ?", login_username, login_password)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    if not data:
        self.forgot_details()
    else:
        reduction = str(data)[1:-1]
        self.loading_bar()
        print("> Your details are: ", str(reduction)[1:-1])
        print("> To log in enter the code below: ")
        self.log_in()
    conn.commit()

def who(self):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT username FROM upgr WHERE code = ?", self.login_code)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    reducing_string = str(data)[1:-1]
    last_cut = str(reducing_string)[1:-1]
    print("> You are successfully logged in as: ", last_cut)
    conn.commit()
    self.login_menu()

def login_menu(self):
    print("")
    print("> Choose one of the following: ")
    print("> 1: Check balance \n"
          "> 2: Check your files \n"
          "> 3: Exit")

    user_ask = input(">  ")
    if user_ask == "1":
        print("Checking balance")
    elif user_ask == "2":
        print("Checking your files")
    elif user_ask == "3":
        print("Application Terminated")
        time.sleep(2)
        self.clear_console()
        sys.exit()
    else:
        self.login_menu()
```

result = Database()
result.txt_menu()

Answer (score 0):

You can execute an UPDATE statement just as you executed your SELECT.
Use the random library to generate your random int between 1 and 10.

```
    import random
    rand_int = random.randrange(1, 10)
    
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    # <- login user here -> #

    # update money
    cursor.execute(f"UPDATE upgr SET money = money + {rand_int} WHERE code = ?", self.login_code)

    conn.commit()
```